# Is my logic correct?

Tags: calculus, functions

The question says there is a function $f(x)$ which maps $R$ to $R$, and $f''(x)>0$ for all x.
This means $f'(x)$ is always increasing.
And it is given that
$$g(x)=2f\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+f\left(6-x^2\right)$$
We need to check the monotonicity of $g(x)$. I first calculate
$$g'(x)=2x\left(f'\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)-f'\left(6-x^2\right)\right)=2x(Q)$$
Since both $Q$ and $x$ vary, we need to keep both in mind.
Also, if
$$f'(x_1)>f'(x_2)$$
$$x_1>x_2$$
Now comes the step I doubt. I suppose
$$Q=f'\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)-f'\left(6-x^2\right)=\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\left(6-x^2\right)\right)R$$
where $R$ is a positive quantity. Then I check where $\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\left(6-x^2\right)\right)$ and $x$ are positive and negative, and arrive at an answer, which my book says is correct.
My logic behind $Q$ and $R$ is that it is $(x_1-x_2)$ that matters which, if negative, makes $Q$ negative.
Is this correct? Does any other "not-going-over-the-head" way apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you doubt is correct. In fact, if $f:X\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly(!) increasing then for $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$,
$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=R>0$$
This is because if $x>y$, $f(x)>f(y)$ so $R>0$ and if $x<y$, $f(x)<f(y)$ and again $R>0$.

Thus for $x,y\in X$, 
$$f(x)-f(y)=R(x-y)\text{ with }R>0$$
(this is trivially true if $x=y$)

Comment: I would want to ask the same question to you as well, which I asked to user7530. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @AshishGaurav user7530 answered that question perfectly. $R$ may not be infinitely times differentiable, so power series are out of the question.

Comment: My point was whether that factor existed, even if it needed a power series. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @AshishGaurav The factor always exists as I showed above

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you have the right idea.

$Q$ is positive if and only if $x^2/2 > 6-x^2$, since $f'$ is monotonic increasing. So to find the intervals where $Q$ is positive, you can instead find the intervals where $x^2/2 - (6-x^2)$ is positive. That is the right approach.

But there is no need to directly involve any $R$.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the function would involve necessarily a factor of (x^2-(6-x^2)) ( of course, if any exp,trigonometric function is there, it can be made infinitely polynomial by Taylor expansion)

Comment: No. It *is* true that you can write $Q(x) = (x^2/2-(6-x^2)) R(x)$ for some positive function $R(x)$, but there is no reason why $R$ has to be constant, polynomial, or "nice" in any way.

Comment: The doubt is, whether the factor would exist. I have no interest in  R (although I would like it if it were 'nice').

Comment: No, even when $Q$ is a polynomial (which is generally not the case), $(x^2/2-(6-x^2))$ is not necessary a "factor" in any usual sense. Consider for instance that $1 = (1+x^2)R(x)$, for the positive function $R(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$. Would you consider $1+x^2$ a factor of 1?

Comment: If you mean, "does there exist a positive function $R(x)$ with $Q = (x^2/6-(6-x^2))R(x)$" then the answer is yes, as discussed by Nameless.